# Cannot read properties of undefined, BUT.. typeOf says "number"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

i wrote a function... the variable b seems to exist and also `block.rows.length`is 0 ! But he tells me "Cannot read properties of undefined"
When you look at my console output, (3) typeof says `block.rows.length`is of type number!

I already tried to clone b with the spread mode.. but still same error.

```
getPCfromStandBlock(b, prices: any[]) {
    let block = {...b}
   console.log("1",block.rows);
   console.log("2",block.rows.length);
   console.log("3",typeof(block.rows.length));
    
    const obj: any = {};
    if (block.rows.length == 0) {
      if (
        block.graphics[0].hasOwnProperty('gaId') &&
        block.graphics[0].pcBlock.length != 0
      ) {
        obj.gaId = block.graphics[0].gaId;
        obj.priceCategory = block.graphics[0].pcBlock[0][0];

        const price = prices.find(
          (p: { pcIndex: any }) => p.pcIndex === obj.priceCategory,
        );

        obj.price = price;
        obj.freePlace = block.graphics[0].pcBlock[0][2];

        return obj;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT

```
1 []
2 0
3 number

/home/watchlist/src/event/event.controller.ts:521
   console.log("2",block.rows.length);
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Comment: Try to Type-cast your block variable as Record<"rows", Array<any>>

Comment: You are *clearly* seeing the error on a separate invocation of your function, otherwise you wouldn't see 3 logged at all. You are passing an invalid object with no rows on a subsequent call. It would probably also help if you didn't turn off the type checker so much. Try logging the value of the parameter b `console.log(JSON.stringify(b));`

Comment: @JaredSmith is correct. You actually wont see #2 or #3 logged if you are getting the error you described. Here is a fiddle showing it: https://jsfiddle.net/g51o2kmj/

Comment: @RyanWheale, yes.. But i see the log of #2 and #3 and I also see the whole object before I pass it to the function.
Could it be a memory leak?

Comment: @JaredSmith:
OUTPUT

{"blockId":"b1937","name":"Stehplatz","blockDescription":"Stehplatz","rows":[],"graphics":[{"hull":true,"gaId":"g1924","type":"polygon","points":[[2884,2149],[2884,4670],[2991,5055],[5192,5055],[5299,4649],[5299,2149]],"pcBlock":[]}]}
1 []
2 0
3 number

/home/watchlist/src/event/event.controller.ts:523
   console.log("1",block.rows);
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rows')


now the error is on #1... And sometimes i get no error with the same data... Very strange

Comment: @MichaelMitch "I also see the whole object before I pass it to the function" `console.log` is a *live view* of the object, not a snapshot of it at the time you logged it (which is why I suggested using JSON.stringify in my other comment). Given that you also say the problem doesn't always happen (and also because the *name* is "rows", query result?), I'm guessing that object is populated asynchronously and you have a race condition between whether it gets added before or after it hits that code. You need to wait for the async op to complete (`await`, `Promise.prototype.then`, etc).